# Where does the memory allocation happens for an underlying object of a static shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, static, shared-ptr

I have come across a class called `Runtime` in GENIVI/capicxx-core-runtime. Part of the code specified below.

```
class Runtime {
 public:
     COMMONAPI_EXPORT static std::shared_ptr<Runtime> get();
     COMMONAPI_EXPORT Runtime();
     COMMONAPI_EXPORT virtual ~Runtime()

 private:
     static std::shared_ptr<Runtime> theRuntime__;
};

std::shared_ptr<Runtime> Runtime::theRuntime__ = std::make_shared<Runtime>();

std::shared_ptr<Runtime> Runtime::get() {
   return theRuntime__;
}
```

My doubt is with the `theRuntime__` variable. Since `shared_ptr` does heap allocation, will the underlying object of `theRuntime__` variable be allocated on heap in this scenario or will it be allocated in BSS/DATA segment?

Comment: If by "underlying object" you mean a `Runtime` instance that `theRuntime__` points to, then it's allocated on the heap by `std::make_shared<Runtime>()` call.

Comment: Memory for object pointed by _shared_ptr_ is taken from heap, but memory for `theRuntime__` object is allocated onto BSS segment - this is static object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The allocation managed by `theRuntime__` (FYI: you're not allowed to use identifiers with double-underscores; they are reserved for the implementation) is created by `std::make_shared`. This will dynamically allocate memory, regardless of where it is called.

The storage for the `theRuntime__` object *itself* is static storage.